# Match template unconditionally

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to call a template function even if `std::enable_if_t` doesn't resolve to `true`. It would allow me to reuse one of my existent templates in other context.

Minimal example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, 
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type>
auto foo(T t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return t;
}

template<typename T>
auto bar(T t) {
    foo(t);
}

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    foo(i); // ok already
    // foo("42"); // shouldn't
    bar("42"); // should
}
```

I tried to solve it bydeclaring a `bool` in template argument list of `foo` and specify it when calling `foo` in `bar`, but I didn't quite manage to compile it without changing how `foo` is getting called in already existent code.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Maybe `std::disjunction`?

Comment: "*I would like to call a template function even if `std::enable_if_t` doesn't resolve to true.*" The *whole point* of `enable_if` is to make a definition disappear if the condition is false. This should only be done if the definition would be non-functional if the condition is not satisfied (ie: you're going to use a copy constructor, but the type doesn't have one). So why is the condition there?

Comment: why is there `std::enable_if` in the first place when you want (and can) call `foo` also in case the condition is not satisfied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want doesn't make sense. Either a call to `foo` is valid or it isn't. It shouldn't matter who does it. `enable_if` is used to ward templates from cases where a particular parameter *cannot* work (or you have an alternate definition where it can). For example, if the definition is going to use a copy constructor, but the type doesn't have one. What you're using it for here doesn't fit that use case.

You can pull out the logic of `foo` into a separate function that both `foo` and `bar` call, if you really need to do something like this.

Comment: Good to know, my use case was that there are two templates for `foo`, one of which is general and technically possible to call for all types. In order to remove template ambiguity I restricted the general version to only left over types. I want to call this general function as if `enable_if` didn't exist in it's definition

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: You're supposed to give them both the same name, and give them inverse `enable_if` conditions.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: You can give the questionable, generic implementation a different name and then wrap it so as to prefer the specific implementations while still allowing opt-in access to the underlying function.

Answer (score 1):

Using **this** SFINAE technique, you can call `foo` for “forbidden” types by not using the default template argument (and therefore not using deduction):

```
template<typename T>
auto bar(T t) {
    return foo<T,void>(t);
}
```

This is of course sometimes cited as a **weakness** of default-type-template-argument SFINAE, along with its inability to constrain multiple, otherwise-equivalent overloads.